# Loop runs more than expected in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

So. Writing application in C, unix, and i have function, which requests user input until input is valid.
lets go straight:

```
int inputX()
{
    int result;
    char input;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Input x (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) :");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        result = validChar(input);
        if (result >= 0)
        {
            return result;  
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invlid input. Lets try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

validChar() checks if input is a - h.
If i input a - everything is fine.
If i input e.g. 1, output is

```
Input x (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) :1
Invlid input. Lets try again.
Input x (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) :Invlid input. Lets try again.
Input x (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) :
```

i even tried sleep(), but didnt work..
C is tricky : |

Comment: Why is this question tagged `c++`?

Comment: I suspect some data is left in the input buffer. Did you examine the contents of `input` on the second iteration? It'll tell you a lot...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C loop prints string twice? (using scanf("%c"))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421926/c-loop-prints-string-twice-using-scanfc)

Comment: How long do you expect this loop to run?

Comment: Did you type only the `1`? Or did you also type `ENTER`?

Comment: `scanf` is notoriously difficult to use correctly, especially when there are errors. I suggest you stick to `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or a manual parsing routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this cheap trick to get rid of blanks left over in the buffer:

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
       ^
```

Comment: Works like a charm! How cold i figure it out, if nobody tells it to me. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those things I wish was taught better.  Unlike most (all?) of the other conversion specifiers like `%d`, `%i`, `%o`, `%x`, `%s`, `%f`, etc., the `%c` conversion specifier does not tell `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace.  This is perfectly logical, because sometimes you *want* to read a whitespace character, but it can cause problems like what you ran into.  You need to use the trick above with the blank before `%c` to get that same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf` with `%c` will make it eat any character. The second run is probably the newline you entered.

Answer (score 0):

The first call picks up `1`. The second call picks up `\n`. Read an entire line and parse it out after.